# Unable to find workaround for color conversion

Tags: c#, wpf, delphi, colors

I have an old application which uses devexpress scheduler, and i am working on new application for it. My problem is in database it has field "LABELCOLOR" of type int. It has values like 536870912, 6610596, 8689404, etc.

Now i need to convert these values to hexadecimal color format using c#, but unable to find any reference how can i do it. I believe these values are integer representation of Delphi colors.

Please guide. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: And what do you want to do now ? Do you want to convert those values in database, write a function which converts Delphi color to C# color or what is your question here ?

Comment: no i have values in DB and i just want to convert them in c#...so that i can bind them as SolidColorBrush in wpf

Comment: Then the linked duplicate question has the answer for you, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C#:  `Console.WriteLine(8689404.ToString("X6"));`

Comment: thanks, it get me to near my solution

Comment: Use "X8" if colors contains alpha (transparency) information